# Azure Logic App - Twitter and MS SQL Connector issues

Tags: sql-server, azure, twitter, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure Logic app that searches for tweets containing **ChinarTrading** and then saves them in the SQL database. Below are the issues I am facing:

- Twitter connector searches tweets only in the twitter account, which I used for authentication. If tweet with **ChinarTrading** is added from some other twitter account, it is not returned in search results.
- Twitter connector returns the same tweets again, how to skip the old tweets.
- In SQL connector, I am using the Insert operation, how can I add a condition like insert if not already existing (tweet text not found).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an Insert operation, use a Stored Procedure. In the stored procedure execute an IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tweets WHERE [TweetId] = 'SomeId')
BEGIN
    --UPDATE HERE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- INSERT HERE
END
```

Comment: There seems to be no option to run procedure, connector only has Insert, Update and Delete operations.

Comment: @SajadDeyargaroo On a related topic, I've a question: If we are adding tweets to SQL Server using Azure Logic Apps, from the following list, in what order the actions should be taken?: Twitter Action, Twitter Trigger, Tweeter Connection, SQL Server Connection

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to add a condition like insert if not already existing.
You can try to do so using the "Add Condition" from the deisgner.

So maybe you can use "SQL Azure- Get Rows" then add a "Condition" then based on the result of the condition you add the action "SQL Azure - Insert Row"

The Insert row API call `POST: /datasets/default/tables/{table}/items` , has only 2 parameters `table` and `item` (Row to insert into the specified table in SQL)
while the Get Rows call allows you to query by (`$skip, $top, $filter, $orderby`)

As for tweets, there is no way at the moment to skip the old tweets as the API call takes only `searchQuery` and `maxResults` parameters as per the [Twitter API documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-create-api-twitter/)